# react countdown timer isn't decrementing well, it is inconsistently changing numbers

Tags: reactjs

**it is not countdowning properly, it begins to go crazy when it reach 50 seconds, I think the problem is in my useEffect but I cant point it,**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function App()
{
   const [minute,setMinute]=useState(1)
   const [second,setSecond]=useState(3)
   const[start,setStart]=useState(false)

const IntervalRef=useRef()
useEffect(()=>{
    if(start==true)
    {
      IntervalRef.current=setInterval(()=>{
            if(second!=0)   
            {
                setSecond(second-1)
            }
            if(second==0&&minute!=0)
            {
                setSecond(59)
                setMinute(minute-1)
            }
            else
            {
                    clearInterval(IntervalRef.current)
            }
       },1000)
    }
})

    return(
       <div>
           {minute}:{second}
    <button onClick={()=>setStart(!start)}>{start?"pause":"start"}</button>

       </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

**it is not countdowning properly, it begins to go crazy when it reach 50 seconds, I think the problem is in my useEffect but I cant point it,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear the interval after each effect runs since the effect runs each render cycle and recreates an interval each time. The effect runs again after each state update. I suspect some clock skew is also to blame and that is why you see the state updates get "out of sync".

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (start == true) {
    IntervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      if (second != 0) {
        setSecond(second - 1);
      }
      if (second == 0 && minute != 0) {
        setSecond(59);
        setMinute(minute - 1);
      } else {
        clearInterval(IntervalRef.current);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  return () => clearInterval(IntervalRef.current); // return an effect cleanup function
});
```

An improved component could use just a seconds state value because computing minutes is trivial.

```
displayMinutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
displaySeconds = seconds % 60;
```

Implementation

```
function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(63);
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);

  const IntervalRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (start) {
      const tick = () => setSeconds(t => t - 1);
      IntervalRef.current = setInterval(tick, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(IntervalRef.current)
    }

    return () => clearInterval(IntervalRef.current)
  }, [start]); // <-- start is dependency so effect runs on mount and only when start is updated

  return (
    <div>
      {Math.floor(seconds / 60)}:{seconds % 60}
      <button onClick={() => setStart(start => !start)}>
        {start ? "pause" : "start"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit toggleable countdown]